# Show a field with information about the practice

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I made 2 forms. 1 form asks which practice you want to choose(dropdown menu). When you press submit it will go to a second form in which you can select options about the practice you just chose.

Now I created a table in phpmyadmin table name: "information" in which I store information about specific practices example: Practice 1 Closed on Mondays, Practice 2 Closed on Fridays.

Now my question is: how can I print information about a specific practice on the screen when that practice is chosen? (the information is stored in the database)

Thanks

Comment: First show us some code so we know where we need to help you. This is way too broad

Comment: could you show us what you have done or tried so far?

Comment: Usually you fetch (`select`) the information from the table in your database with conditions (`where`) using Sql...

Comment: @Darren Yes I figured it out I used select and made a while loop.